# Angular2 - Dynamically create routerLink when changing innerHTML in directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a directive that I have created in angular2 that changes the `innerHTML` of an HTML element.  Here is a simple version of the directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[fieldName]'
})

export class FieldNameDirective implements DoCheck {
    element: HTMLElement;

    @Input('fieldName')
    fieldId: number;

    cached: number;

    constructor(
        el: ElementRef,
        private moduleService: ModuleService) {
        this.element = el.nativeElement;
    }

    ngDoCheck() {
        if (this.cached != this.fieldId) {
            // store cached
            this.cached = this.fieldId;
            this.element.innerHTML = 'TEST ME';


        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to change this directive so that it can contain a router link path, something like this

```
if (this.fieldId == 1)
    this.element.innerHTML = 'NORMAL TEXT';
else
    this.element.innerHTML = '<a routerLink="/path/to/go/to">TEXT WITH LINK</a>';
```

But doing this doesn't seem to actually generate a `href` link on the `a` tag.

In angular1, I think I would need to use the `$compile` service and compile the HTML for it to work. Do I have to do something similar in angular2, a and if so how?

I am using the new `@angular/router` not the deprecated one.

Comment: I have a similar situation, how did you solved it eventually?

Comment: A possible option https://stackoverflow.com/a/49435440/943646

Answer (score 4):

Angular doesn't do anything (except sanitization) for HTML added dynamically.

- no bindings resolved (`[...]`, `(...)`, `xxx="{{...}}`
- no directives or components instantiated
- no CSS view encapsulation emulation (_ng_content_xxx attributes are not added)

You can use `*ngIf` to show hide the one element or the other or
you can add components dynamically using `ViewContainerRef.createComponent` like explained and demonstrated in [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)