# Angular2 Dynamic HTML with functional RouterLink

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives

Long time user, first time question asker!  I've been trying to figure this out for the better part of two days to no avail, so here we go.

**Dynamic compiled templates from external sources in Angular2?**

I am using http to get page content in the form of HTML from the WordPress API.  So I have a template like this:

```
    <div [innerHTML]="contentHTML"> </div>
```

and "contentHTML" is a string variable in the component and assigned a value asynchronously via the API call to something like this:

```
    <a routerLink="/help/faq.html"> </a>
```

and I want that routerLink to work.  Of course routerLink could be anything that's valid in a template.

**If the above is not possible**

If the above isn't going to work, what about a way to interpret the incoming HTML and add routerLinks on the fly to replace standard hrefs?

Comment: duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44949958/how-do-i-dynamically-load-and-display-html-which-contains-routerlink-directives

Essentially just do a click listener for your whole innerHtml and check for your routerLink attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across the same issue, I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41062570/5224768), but added a simple modification in the code where you import **DynamicComponentModule**, but added **imports: [RouterModule]**

So the steps would be as following install **[ng-dynamic](https://github.com/laco0416/ng-dynamic)**:

```
npm install --save ng-dynamic
```

Then use the following import and code:

```
import { DynamicComponentModule } from 'ng-dynamic';

@NgModule({
   imports: [
       ...
       DynamicComponentModule.forRoot({imports: [RouterModule]}),
       ...
   ],
   ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then instead of:

```
<div [innerHTML]="contentHTML"> </div>
```

Use:

```
<div *dynamicComponent="contentHTML"></div>
```

hope this helps!

Comment: ng-dynamic has a good few open issues. Is it still viable for prod build with Angular v5+ ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I am using it with Angular 5+ just fine, at first I needed to updated it to the latest version when I upgraded my angular

Comment: @AdhamSabry I'm curious did you manage to use AOT compiler as well in your setup?

Comment: @tomaszBlachut: yes

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution without using Dynamic runtime compilation **when using hash location strategy** is to use the following HTML

```
<a onclick="window.location.reload()" href="#/pages/Home">Click</a>
```

where `/pages/Home` is an angular route. This will be set into a div as follows

```
<ng-container *ngIf='content'>
  <div [innerHTML]="content.text"></div>
</ng-container>
```

This will trigger a reload on the destination, hence handing over stuff to angular router.

### UPDATE 1

I used a neater workaround for this using custom events. I added a custom js as follows

```
function navigate_in_primary(url) {
    var evt = new CustomEvent('content_navigate', { detail: { url: url, primary: true } });
    window.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

I listen to this event using RxJs, in constructor of a custom service injected into `app.module`

```
Observable.fromEvent<Event>(window, 'content_navigate')
.subscribe((event)=>{
    this.router.navigateByUrl(event.detail.url);
})
```

Finally, my HTML

```
<a onclick="navigate_in_primary('/pages/home.aspx')" class="grey-button">SIGN IN</a>
```

Comment: Agreed. But I had a lot of other scenarios where I had to use hash as my app was a cordova based mobile app. I will reword my answer to reflect the same.

Comment: The simplest and best solution I have seen.

Comment: Using browser events as a mediator between dynamic content and the compiled Angular code is really clever. Kudos.

Comment: If you want to be IE11 compliant, then the creation of CutomEvent needs to be done using this approach: `document.createEvent('CustomEvent')`

Answer (score 1):

After much digging, I found the answer to [Angular 2.1.0 create child component on the fly, dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060498/angular-2-1-0-create-child-component-on-the-fly-dynamically) very useful in getting things working!

**THE SECRET SAUCE!!!**

Checkout the 

  
    **[complete Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/mcvILwmOLvrS2PxIrXX8?p=preview)**
  
 
by [yurzui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5485167/yurzui) for details, but in a nutshell, make sure that the *DynamicHtmlModule* class which creates the runtime compiled component **has a reference to the *RouterModule*** module.  Otherwise *routerLink* directives used in the dynamic template will not work. I've bolded the key piece of code below.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, <strong>RouterModule</strong>],
  declarations: [decoratedCmp]}) class DynamicHtmlModule { }

  return compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(DynamicHtmlModule)
   .then((moduleWithComponentFactory: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any>) => {
     return moduleWithComponentFactory.componentFactories
      .find(x => x.componentType === decoratedCmp);
  });
}
```

The same is going to be true for any other directive or component your template might use.  You have to make sure your *DynamicHtmlModule* properly references them to get them to work.