# Use angular router inside markdown links

Tags: angular, markdown

I'm using ngx-markdown to render my FAQ, in it, I've links to external resource (starting `http`) and internal stuff (starting with `/`).

I'd like to pass the angular router to my markedOptionsFactory in order to use it for local resources.

Is there a way to pass angular router in the decorator when importing the module:

```
imports: [
    [...]
    MarkdownModule.forRoot({
        provide: MarkedOptions,
        useFactory: markedOptionsFactory,
    }),
    [...]
],
```

FYI, my `markedOptionsFactory` looks like:

```
export function markedOptionsFactory(): MarkedOptions {
    const renderer = new MarkedRenderer();

    renderer.link = (href: string, title: string, text: string) => {
        const isLocalLink = /^\//.test(href);
        const target = isLocalLink ? '_self' : '_blank';
        const hrefContent = isLocalLink ? `javascript:router.navigateByUrl('${href}')` : href;

        return `<a href="${hrefContent}" target="${target}">${text}</a>`;
};

    return {
        renderer: renderer,
        [...]
    };
}
```

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: @maxime1992, I had my workaround below, I hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks! Alexandre you could check that answer which helped me :) 
https://github.com/jfcere/ngx-markdown/issues/125#issuecomment-538735982

Answer (score 1):

I did not found direct solution from Angular. I had to create a Custom Event from marked.js and then catch it higher in the DOM tree.

Here some piece of code of my work around:

- First: trigger event from a link (instead of the default routing behavior)

```
renderer.link = (href: string, title: string, text: string) => {
  const isLocalLink = /^\//.test(href);

  let hrefContent;
  if (isLocalLink) {
    hrefContent = `javascript:document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('routeTo', {detail: '${href}'})); void(0)`;
  } else {
    hrefContent = href;
  }

  return `<a href="${hrefContent}">${text}</a>`;
};
```

- Then: catch that event from highest coponent/module possible with:

```
this.window.document.addEventListener('routeTo', (e: CustomEvent) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  router.navigateByUrl(e.detail);
}, false);
```

**Be careful** with Internet Explorer, you will need a polyfill for Custom Event

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, which is based on a suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55874196/1626109)

Define an angular directive

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Directive({
  selector: '[appInterceptRouterlink]'
})
export class InterceptRouterlinkDirective {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  @HostListener("click", ["$event"])
  public onClick(e: MouseEvent): void {
    const srcElem = e.target;
    if (srcElem instanceof HTMLAnchorElement)
    {
      const baseURI = srcElem.baseURI ;
      const href = srcElem.href ;

      if (href.startsWith(baseURI))
      {
        const baseURILength = baseURI.length;
        const routerlink = href.substring(baseURILength);
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        this.router.navigate([routerlink]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Use the directive in the markdown tag, in my case as follows

```
<markdown [data]="markdown" appInterceptRouterlink></markdown>
```

The HostListener in the directive looks for links which start with the base URL and handles them as routerlinks.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44485006/10202440)**
hope this helps!