# How can I use a routerLink inside an HTML string?

Tags: angular

I have a long piece of text to display in my app and so I want to use a string of HTML.

```
// component
description: string = `<p>Hello world. <a routerLink="/home">Click here</a> to go to the home page.</p>`;

// template
<div class="content">
  <div innerHTML="description"></div>
</div>
```

This renders correctly, except Angular strips out the `routerLink` piece and the link doesn't work.  I have tried using a custom pipe to pass the string through the `DomSanitizer` function `bypassSecurityTrustHtml()`, but Angular doesn't pick up on the syntax and does not treat it as a `routerLink`.

Comment: a word of advice, in 2019, if you ever find yourself writing `innerHTML` you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Stavm Care to explain why? That is required for embed string-based HTML in Angular as I understand it.

Comment: what is the purpose of using routerLink here? why don't you just put a regular [href]?

Comment: @MauroAguilar Same reason anyone would use routerLink: to activate the path using the Angular router: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: You can't. The angular directives must be part of the template to be compiled by the Angular compiler.

Comment: @Stewart but I think Angular compiler won't understand that because the dynamic rendering of HTML will happen at runtime. Have you tried href ?

Comment: @MauroAguilar href "works" but does not use the Angular router. It reloads the whole app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to pass angular routerLink URL's in an HTML string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55873569/best-way-to-pass-angular-routerlink-urls-in-an-html-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short, useless answer is "You can't".

---

At the end of the day, Angular as a framework is about generating and updating the DOM in an efficient and understandable way. By using the `innerHtml` binding, you're telling Angular "I know what I'm doing, just put this string in the DOM" - which it happily does after sanitizing truly dangerous things (like `<script>` tags). Since you're telling Angular exactly what should be in the DOM, it doesn't bother with any additional processing (like parsing directives).

---

So, how do you make this work?

Instead of using `innerHtml` you need to use an actual component. This will likely be a pain to re-work, but it allows you to use Angular bindings and custom styles.

---

If you need help with that specific re-work, I recommend you ask a new question with that information

Answer (score 1):

If you definitely can't put this in an Angular template you would need to query the anchors dynamically and instantiate the Router provider to navigate programmatically. Something like:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private ref: ElementRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  const anchors = [...this.ref.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a')];
  anchors.forEach((a) => a.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.router.navigate([a.href]);
  }));
}
```

Kind of ugly though...

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can define a `(click)` method on which you can `navigate` to the required route.

AFAIK, dynamically rendered templates won't bind  `routerLink` properties

Answer (score 0):

I want to make a not here that if you have a link with `hre="/foo"` and you want to parse, just using `this.router.navigate([a.href])` will not work properly because `a.href` will be evaluated to **the entire URL**, meaning: `http://localhost:4200/foo` - this is not what you want since that won't match an angular route!

Here's what I ended up doing, pulling from answers in this question:

First, I marked all the links that I needed to be parsed like this with `rel="ng"` to separate them from any other links that don't need to be parsed

```ts
this.myHtmlElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll<HTMLAnchorElement>('a[rel="ng"]').forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    void this.router.navigate([link.attributes.getNamedItem('href')?.value]);
  });
});
```