# Angular2 - Dynamically include routerLink in string

Tags: angular, dynamic, angular6, routerlink

I'm using the mean stack with Angular 6 and i'm currently creating a notification system. I'm getting 'events' from my database and I want to be able to display their messages which may contain url links to other parts of the site. For example one might contain a message which is:

```
New job created <a [routerLink]="['/job', job._id]">{{jobName}}</a>
```

I can't use innerHTML as it strips the routerLink. So how do I evaluate it as a link?

I've tried ng-dynamic as suggested here: 
[Angular2 Dynamic HTML with functional RouterLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123385/angular2-dynamic-html-with-functional-routerlink)

However I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _angular_compiler__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.JitCompilerFactory is not a constructor
```

Comment: Well from my reading it seems if you switch to JIT compiler (and maybe do tweak some more options) error mentioned by you will go away because ng-dynamic seems quite outdated. But it isn't a solution really... Upvoted because you've piqued my curiosity

Comment: Just to add some options from me, if you control backend, consider sending object like `{prefix, suffix, url, label}` instead of ready HTML and then create template `{{prefix}}<a [routerLink]="url">{{label}}</a>{{suffix}}`. Maybe you even don't need suffix.

Comment: I could do something like that, but what if I want multiple links? And the structure of the message isn't consistent? This must be a common issue for something like a blog post..?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that Angular authors wanted us to do things like that (dynamic directive instantiation). In your first example simple ngFor will suffice but 
I can agree that it will feel somewhat superfluous.

Comment: You could always make own, limited directive for intercepting links. RouterLink at it's core is only a few lines: 
`@HostListener('click', [...])
  onClick(button: number, ctrlKey: boolean, metaKey: boolean, shiftKey: boolean): boolean {
[...]
    this.router.navigateByUrl(this.urlTree, extras);
    return false;
  }`

Comment: Hello @MichaelB. Have you found a solution by any chance?